# Delete or voice over all text in Dragon Dictation free app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation

I have an iPhone 6 running ios9 and the free app for Dragon Dictation.

Is there a command or sequence of commands (voice or keyboard) to delete everything in the recording and start over?

I've just started experimenting with the Dragon Dictation free app. So far, it's my understanding that:

- Once you've started, the only way to start over is to send the recording (such as to email).
- You can use the keyboard (NOT voice commands) for discrete edits, such as to cut, copy, or delete a single word.
- Dragon Diction free app is limited to the same commands as Siri; it can do everything that Siri can, and nothing more.

The other posts I found on stackexchange appeared to ask about those small, discrete kinds of deletions. My question is about deleting all of the text. Affirmations or corrections about my understanding of the capabilities of the free app are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the entire recording using the keyboard:

1. Tap keyboard.
2. Tap screen.
3. Tap and SELECT ALL.
4. Tap CUT.

If you don't see SELECT ALL, then tap again to dismiss the choices, and try tapping lightly in a different area of the screen.